# OSX how to have three controls(textbox or popup or combobox) of same width?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, autolayout

I have a window with three control on it. I want them to make resizable with respect to the window.

- Distance from window boundary should be constant
- Distance between each of them be constant

[image]

How to achieve this with cocoa Autolayout feature from Xcode?

Answer (score 1):

I used few contraints as:

- For the first object -> set the Leading space to superview say 20.
- For the last object -> set the Trailing space to superview say 20.
- For the centre object -> set the Leading & Trailing to other controls on either side.
- To make them equi-resize -> Select all of them, and select Equal Widths from Pin item.
  [image]